Proper QML Dialog integration with QtWidget QMainWindow
I have a QtWidget application comprising of a QMainWindow from which other QDialogs are opened from. I want to slowly migrate the application to QtQuick by converting each QDialog to a QML Dialog, then finally converting the QMainWindow to a QML ApplicationWindow.
Until the migration is complete, the application will momentarily be a hybrid of a QMainWindow opening both QDialogs and QML Dialogs.
So my question is what is the proper way to create and open a QML Dialog from a QtWidget QMainWindow?
I am using Qt >= 5.15.0

It's not impossible to use QtWidgets and QML, but it's usually done when actually necessary: showing the two isn't so difficult (see this example, but many others exist), interfacing them is a further step, depending on the complexity of the elements and the requirements of their interaction, and may need different approaches depending on the case. While you could make an abstract interface layer that can be used in various situations, it makes little sense to go through all that for something that will eventually be removed: just complete the QML port.
